# How can i upload more than one jpg with AJAX and symfony2 Doctrine

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

I know that its easy to upload single image with symfony and doctrine2.
But i want to have system like Google docs where i can see the progress bar of current image upload using doctrine2.

I know want to use thirdparty plugin.

Because i need to create an entity for everyimage and store it database with some detail. So i can just bulk upload with third party software in directory

is it possible or not

Comment: use any of ajax based uploaders e.g. valium uploader and you can upload/monitor multiple files

Comment: But how can i simultaneously process with symfony controller to make them entity and insert record in database , after every image uploaded. i don't want to first upload all images and then process

Comment: before uploading save the entities in DB , and then call the upload script

Comment: I mean i need to make every image uploaded as an entity in database to process and link with other objects. So if i have 10 images , i need to make 10 entities object of my photo class

Comment: to be honest, why would you save the img to db , I will prefer uploading them into a external directory and just save the paths instead

Comment: i am not saving the image but its properties like original name ,size, dimensions , then i need to rename it with id of user who is uploading in separate folders based on size and all that

Answer (score 0):

You may try **[AX Ajax Multi Uploader](http://code.google.com/p/ax-jquery-multiuploader/)**

Here is their homepage http://www.albanx.com/ (not relevant though)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to upload the file at client side .

Refer http://fineuploader.com/demos.html.
you can browse your files and trigger upload automatically or if you want to process the data at client side (say for a preview) you can process and trigger the upload manually as well.

you can also refer http://www.queness.com/post/11434/7-javascript-ajax-file-upload-plugins

and choose the lib which fits your requirement.